# Conversion of .gml (MultiLineStringZ) to .shp (Polygon)

Tags: python, shapefile, geopandas, convert, gml

I want to convert .gml (Type: MultiLineStringZ) to .shp (Type: Polygon) and only save the respective height (Attribute: measuredHeight) data given in the .gml to the shp. I already tried out the following solutions:

1. Polygonize in QGIS: This produced an empty attribute table but it is my only "solution" so far that produced polygons
2. Conversion over gdal (gml > raster > polygon)
3. Join the height attribute with the empty polygons produced in 1. with "join by location"
4. Conversion via convex_hull (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2964751/how-to-convert-a-geos-multilinestring-to-polygon):
5. Conversion with geopandas and shapely: I have not been able to convert the lines into polygons yet but used the following code so far as I was hoping to convert them into polygons later. My attempt, to use "vectorize" in QGIS produced polygons that could only be displayed as polylines which were not closed in all cases.

> ```
> import geopandas as gpd
> import fiona
> from shapely.geometry import LineString, MultiLineString
>
> # Read the MultiLineStringZ from the GML file
> gml = gpd.read_file("LoD2_338_5677_1_NW.gml")
>
> # Convert the MultiLineStringZ to a MultiLineString object
> multilinestringz = gml.geometry.iloc[0]
> multilinestring = MultiLineString([LineString(line) for line in multilinestringz])
>
> # Write the MultiLineString to a shapefile
> schema = {'geometry': 'MultiLineString', 'properties': {'id': 'int'}}
> with fiona.open('multiline.shp', 'w', 'ESRI Shapefile', schema) as output:
>     output.write({'geometry': mapping(multilinestring), 'properties': {'id': 1}})
> ```

1: [image] 2: [image]

5: [image]

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: This seems like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) - could you describe what you are trying to do as well as what you have tried so far.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I'm aware of the XY problem, but I'm not sure to what you're referring to. I have a city model with height data given in .gml format and want to transform it to polygons (ideally .shp). For this, I tried the approaches above. My main problem is that the conversion does not work and produces either polylines or empty polygons. Could you clarify what is not clear to you?

Comment: converting polylines to polygons is trivial if (and only if) they make valid polygons. Clearly there's something off about your data or your process, so why not break it down - convert from GML to GeoPackage (or shapefile if you must) then look at the line->polygon issue. Edit down your question to what is going wrong and show us a small bit of input and a small bit of output.